# Disable html5 canvas click events

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a canvas element, and in the canvas if you click a button it opens a `div` modal. The modal then has some buttons on it, and if you click on one of the buttons and it is also above a button in the canvas, the canvas button also gets clicked.

I would like to disable the canvas, but I can't seem to do so. I have a tried applying css styles to the `canvas` like so:

```
pointer-events: none
```

But the canvas still accepts the clicks. Is there any way for me to disable the canvas so that I can click on the modal without it affecting the canvas?

The canvas contains a game, and the game isn't always the same, so I don't have access to the canvas' code to disable the buttons in the canvas.

Comment: instead of disabling the click event on the campus, simply stop the click event on the button from bubbling

Comment: I'm actually having a hard time recreating the scenario where a html button is above a canvas and the click events bubbling to the canvas element.. are you sure there's not another element catching the events? Or that maybe the button is positioned UNDER the canvas? (in which case you should just give it a position and higher z-index)

Comment: I'll toss another scenario out there.. do the buttons have the same ID? does the modals button get the click event?

Comment: The canvas that I am testing with is built with `construct 2`, so I am not sure what that is doing in the background.

Answer (score 5):

First, you set it up like this:

```
<div class='your-canvas-wrapper'>
<canvas>
...
</canvas>
</div>
```

If you want to disable on page load.

```
.your-canvas-wrapper {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you want to disable after page load, you can do this...

```
$(".your-canvas-wrapper").css("cursor", "not-allowed");
$(".your-canvas-wrapper").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

Comment: canvas{ pointer-events: none; }  would be enough I think

Answer (score 4):

You can simply make a handler such as

```
const c = document.querySelector("#myCanvas")
c.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (c.classList.contains('disabled')) {return}
    // Do not perform default action, stop bubbling the event
    e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation()

    // Mark event as invalid for older browsers
    return false
})
```

#### Edit: More Conclusive solution

```css
.canvas-wrapper {position:relative}
.canvas-wrapper:after {content:'';position:absolute;z-index:999;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;cursor: not-allowed;    pointer-events: none}
```

```html
<div class='canvas-wrapper'>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

This creates a *faux* blocking element atop your `canvas` element, this way it gathers all click events before they can even hit the `canvas` (*since the canvas is under this element*)

Comment: this question isn't tagged with [tag:jquery]

Comment: Fixed, with vanilla js declaration, I had included jQuery just for reference

Comment: Adding `stopPropagation` doesn't work, as I can still click on the modal button but the canvas still picks it up.

Comment: Edited with a different solution which should work in all probabilities

Answer (score 0):

Event Propagation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

In the event handler for the button click, stop the propagation of the event.

Comment: Adding `stopPropagation` doesn't work, as I can still click on the modal button but the canvas still picks it up.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Could you provide some code then, so we could better help you? It is likely that you will want to include `e.stopPropagation` in your solution. This is not an issue with a simple canvas / div. https://jsfiddle.net/7cd14prr/